# Rails 6 Asset Pipeline: How to import vendor scripts in application.js?

Tags: jquery, webpack, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to properly import vendor js files in my application.js under `app/javascript/packs/application.js`

This is the current architecture:

[image: javascript-folder-architecture]

As is possible to see, I choose to put vendor js files in `app/javascrip/plugins/`

I've structured the `application.js` like this:

```js
// Rails Internals
require("@rails/ujs").start();
require("turbolinks").start();
require("@rails/activestorage").start();
require("channels");

// Libraries/Vendor-plugins
require("jquery");
import 'bootstrap';
require('../plugins/chosen.min.js');
require('../plugins/magnific-popup.min.js');
require('../plugins/owl.carousel.min.js');
require('../plugins/rangeSlider');
require('../plugins/sticky-kit.min.js');
require('../plugins/masonry.min.js');
require('../plugins/mmenu.min.js');
require('../plugins/tooltips.min.js');
require('../plugins/custom');


// Custom functions
// import { myFunction } from '../components/myScrip';

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
});
```

By doing this, the jQuery should be accesible by the `custom.js` file located in `app/javascript/plugins/custom.js`, right?

To make things clear, the `custom.js` has this shape:

```js
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function () {
      // ...
    }
})(this.jQuery);
```

But when I run the server, the jQuery can't be found:

[image: jquery-error]

I've added jQuery and bootstrap via `yarn add jquery@3.5.1 bootstrap@3.4.1` (old versions needed by the vendor).

My Webpack enviroment.js is like this:

```js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker');
const webpack = require('webpack');

environment.plugins.prepend(
  'Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
  })
);

module.exports = environment;
```

I tried to find answer in [The Asset Pipeline on Ruby Guides.](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#search-paths) but seems that the tutorial is a little out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I don't know if this is the best approach, but I manage to solve the problem.

To do that I wrapped the `custom.js` with:

```js
const custom = () => {

  (function (root, factory) {
    if (root === undefined && window !== undefined) root = window;
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
      // AMD. Register as an anonymous module unless amdModuleId is set
      define(["jquery"], function (a0) {
        return (factory(a0));
      });
    } else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
      // Node. Does not work with strict CommonJS, but
      // only CommonJS-like environments that support module.exports,
      // like Node.
      module.exports = factory(require("jquery"));
    } else {
      factory(root["jQuery"]);
    }
  }(this, function (jQuery) {
   (function ($) { // start of custom.js file.
    "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function () {
      // ...
    }
})(jQuery); // end of custom.js file.
}
```

I still having little issues with some things inside of `custom.js` but at least it is being loaded properlly.

Better ideas on how to solve this please post your answer. Cya!

Answer (score 5):

Add your new directory to the lookup file of webpacker.

In `config/webpacker.yml` add:

```
additional_paths: ['your/path']
```

In this specific case:

```
additional_paths: ['app/javascript/plugins/']
```

Comment: this saves me a ton of time, working on rails 6.1 webpacker, vendor/assets tested and working... nice!

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use this in your `$ruby_app/app/javascript/packs/application.js` just to declare jQuery

```
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
```